Having one Azure Monitor Alert Rule for all severities
We use Azure Monitor to flag issues in our environments, such as VMs with disks nearing capacity.  Typically we have 3 different thresholds with related severities; e.g.

Critical: (free disk space) <= 1%
Error: 1% < (free disk space) <= 5%
Warning: 5% < (free disk space) <= 10%

We define these alerts in Terraform, so the implementation for one of these looks something like this (I've removed a bunch of bits to give the gist):
resource "azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert_v2" "azure_tf_monitor_alert" {
  name                = "VM Free Disk Space - ERROR"
  severity            = 1 # error
  criteria {
    threshold               = 0
    operator                = "GreaterThan"
    query                   = <<-QUERY
      Perf
      | where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
      | where ObjectName in~ ('LogicalDisk', 'Logical Disk') and CounterName =~ '% Free Space'  
      | where not (InstanceName in~ ("_Total" , "total" )) and not (InstanceName startswith "/snap")
      | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, CounterValue) by Computer, InstanceName, _ResourceId
      | project Computer, InstanceName, _ResourceId, CounterValue, TimeGenerated 
      | where CounterValue > 1 and CounterValue <= 5
      QUERY
      # etc...
  }
  # etc...
}

We then have almost the same rule 3 times; the only differences being:



name ending
severity
last line of query




WARNING
2
where CounterValue > 5 and CounterValue <= 10


ERROR
1
where CounterValue > 1 and CounterValue <= 5


CRITICAL
0
where CounterValue <= 1



This feels inefficient - we could easily have 1 rule called VM Free Disk Space and amend the SQL to return a value for Severity by having the last line of the query be something like this:
| where CounterValue <= 10         // ignore the healthy stuff
| extend Severity = case (
          CounterValue <= 1,  0,   // Critical
          CounterValue <= 5,  1,   // Error
          2                        // Warning by default
  )

However, so far as I can tell there's no way to take the severity value produced by the query and apply it to the rule's severity setting.
The terraform does allow us to have a threshold setting, so whilst I have this set to 0 meaning if we get any matches, go to the fired state we could adjust our output to return the CounterValue directly then have different criteria blocks with different thresholds; but from what I can tell we can only have 1 criteria block and besides, severity isn't set within that block but is in the parent resource.
Obviously we can put this terraform in a module and create 3 rules from a single definition (in fact, we have); but this feels inefficient / suggests to me that MS is running the same query 3 times just to handle the 3 scenarios despite it being essentially the same query...
Is there a better approach that we're missing?

If you need to use several severity levels then you need to create an alert rule for each one.
What exactly do you mean by "inefficient"? Are you worried about the code duplication?

Code duplication was my main gripe (solved by using a module), but by inefficient I meant MS has to run that query periodically to assess the alert's condition; if we have 3 rules then that's being run 3 times as often, which seems silly given we only care about the output (i.e. if I were coding an application with a database backend I'd run one query then use its result in a switch statement, rather than having each case block rerun the query when evaluating its condition).

Apples (alert rules) and oranges (databases)? :-)

Maybe... In the background the alert rules are still sending queries to a (time series) database; but we're not billed based on that so perhaps shouldn't care - it's the developer in me; people from an ops background don't seem to mind as much.

I have a software development background as well. But Databases, application code (.NET, Java, etc) and IaC are all different things and must be treated as such.

If you need to use several severity levels then you need to create an alert rule for each one.
In order to reduce code duplication, you can use a module (as you already mentioned) or, as an alternative, a template file for the queries like the following:
my-module/templates/alert-rule.tpl
Perf
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
| where ObjectName in~ ('LogicalDisk', 'Logical Disk') and CounterName =~ '% Free Space'  
| where not (InstanceName in~ ("_Total" , "total" )) and not (InstanceName startswith "/snap")
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, CounterValue) by Computer, InstanceName, _ResourceId
| project Computer, InstanceName, _ResourceId, CounterValue, TimeGenerated 
| where ${condition}

It is possible to customize the condition in the last line: where ${condition}
The below example shows how to use a map for each alert rule/severity. I'm using a null_resource for the sake of simplicity, but it should be easy enough to adapt this code to your case:
main.tf
locals {
  alert_rules = {
    "warning" = {
      name      = "VM Free Disk Space - WARNING"
      severity  = 2
      condition = "where CounterValue > 5 and CounterValue <= 10"
    },
    "error" = {
      name      = "VM Free Disk Space - ERROR"
      severity  = 1
      condition = "where CounterValue > 1 and CounterValue <= 5"
    },
    "critical" = {
      name      = "VM Free Disk Space - CRITICAL"
      severity  = 0
      condition = "where CounterValue <= 1"
    }
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "alert_rules" {
  for_each = local.alert_rules

  triggers = {
    name      = each.value.name
    severity  = each.value.severity
    condition = each.value.condition

    query = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/alert-rule.tpl", {
      condition = each.value.condition
    })
  }
}

Running terraform plan:
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # null_resource.alert_rules["critical"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "alert_rules" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "condition" = "where CounterValue <= 1"
          + "name"      = "VM Free Disk Space - CRITICAL"
          + "query"     = <<-EOT
                Perf
                | where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
                | where ObjectName in~ ('LogicalDisk', 'Logical Disk') and CounterName =~ '% Free Space'  
                | where not (InstanceName in~ ("_Total" , "total" )) and not (InstanceName startswith "/snap")
                | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, CounterValue) by Computer, InstanceName, _ResourceId
                | project Computer, InstanceName, _ResourceId, CounterValue, TimeGenerated 
                | where where CounterValue <= 1
            EOT
          + "severity"  = "0"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.alert_rules["error"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "alert_rules" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "condition" = "where CounterValue > 1 and CounterValue <= 5"
          + "name"      = "VM Free Disk Space - ERROR"
          + "query"     = <<-EOT
                Perf
                | where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
                | where ObjectName in~ ('LogicalDisk', 'Logical Disk') and CounterName =~ '% Free Space'  
                | where not (InstanceName in~ ("_Total" , "total" )) and not (InstanceName startswith "/snap")
                | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, CounterValue) by Computer, InstanceName, _ResourceId
                | project Computer, InstanceName, _ResourceId, CounterValue, TimeGenerated 
                | where where CounterValue > 1 and CounterValue <= 5
            EOT
          + "severity"  = "1"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.alert_rules["warning"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "alert_rules" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "condition" = "where CounterValue > 5 and CounterValue <= 10"
          + "name"      = "VM Free Disk Space - WARNING"
          + "query"     = <<-EOT
                Perf
                | where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
                | where ObjectName in~ ('LogicalDisk', 'Logical Disk') and CounterName =~ '% Free Space'  
                | where not (InstanceName in~ ("_Total" , "total" )) and not (InstanceName startswith "/snap")
                | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, CounterValue) by Computer, InstanceName, _ResourceId
                | project Computer, InstanceName, _ResourceId, CounterValue, TimeGenerated 
                | where where CounterValue > 5 and CounterValue <= 10
            EOT
          + "severity"  = "2"
        }
    }

Plan: 3 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.


Thanks for confirming / good info on template files too; I'd not come across that feature... I'd probably stick with a module, or go with a foreach on the resource itself for this scenario, but good to know there's other options out there; thanks.

@JohnLBevan I'd avoid using heredoc strings directly in the resources - IMO it makes the code harder to read. Google recommends to Place lengthy HereDocs in external files, separate from their HCL as well.

Ah; just reread your code / saw the template's being used to hold the query and substitute in the additional condition at the same time, rather than templating the azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert_v2 resource - sorry, I got distracted by the templatefile documentation so didn't pay enough attention to the detail of your answer.  Using it for just the query is nice.

@JohnLBevan mine is just an example, I'm using null_resource because I don't have an Azure subscription at the moment. But you can use the templatefile to set the query directly in the azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert_v2 resource. Whatever makes your life easier.

Makes sense - what I meant was that on first read I thought you'd defined the azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert_v2 within the template - which I don't like as that puts TF code into something that's not syntax checked as TF code - but on seeing you'd only put the query in there it made sense, as that makes the query nicely parameterised, whilst keeping all the benefits of having the rest of the TF in a TF file.
